# My nginx log not read the web activity in real time

Tags: nginx, mod-security

I am confused, my nginx log does not read the web activity in real time. The log will tell what happens after several time (it is hours ).

Do you know why?

Thanks

Comment: I never had problem with it. Logs are often gziped, did you uncompress them before read?

Comment: hi, I have to set up that I forgot. Thanks the comment

Comment: Actually I assume that you are running into a buffering issue. The Nginx logging is able to buffer its output to accelerate the HTTP serving. If the buffer is  large and there are not many requests, it will need some time to fill the buffer and write it to the log file. For more details post your logging configuration.